# Paypal pay for invoice with REST API

Tags: list, api, paypal, payment, invoice

Here is the situation.
Someone has PayPal account and sends invoice to me. I have to PAY for the invoice. If I log into my account the invoice is there.

Can I list the invoices that are sent to me via API and pay for them with API request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, this is not something that is available right now.